# -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f1e9f90

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

guys i have an array6 that contains data which coming from webservice..
output of :-`NSLog(@"%@",[array6 description]);`

```
(
        (
        "Thu 8, Jan",
        "Thu 8, Jan"

    )
)
```

i have a custom table view "availPassengerTableViewCell"..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    availPassengerTableViewCell *cell = (availPassengerTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"availPassengerTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
   cell.phoneLbl.text = [array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //here it showing above error..

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `array6` and `array3` what is the content of those ?

Comment: NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"availPassengerTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]; How you are expecting an array as result of right hand statement.

Comment: sorry guys that is array6 instead of array3..correct is cell.phoneLbl.text = [array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: `array3` and `array6`? Array names should be meaningful which will helpful you in near future when you have web of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the NSLog it seems like your array contains another array in it and that inside array has the elements that you want to show in your tableview.

So change:

```
 cell.phoneLbl.text = [array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to:

```
 cell.phoneLbl.text = array6[0][indexPath.row];
```

Comment: good solution but it showing only 1st element of array6..the response i get into array 6 and it could be changeable...e.g. array6 could be(
        (
        "Thu 8, Jan",
        "Thu 9, Jan",
        "Thu 6, Jan"
    )
)

Comment: @AbhishekNagar: Check your `numberOfRowsInSection` implementation

Comment: return[array6 count];

Comment: @AbhishekNagar: Change that to `return [array6[0] count];`

Answer (score 0):

The nightmare is this line,  `cell.phoneLbl.text = [array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

You're happy to show some string from `array6` but unfortunately there's no string object at particular index path (row). Instead there's an `NSArray` object.

Please make sure for these,

1. Update your response (from wherever you're getting).
2. Correct your code as per the response.
3. Make code as simple as possible.